# tf.keras mixed precision loss scale still causing underflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

When I use mixed precision for my tf.keras model, my model's loss isn't going down at all. I noticed that my gradients often either end up at "nan" values or "-inf" or "inf" after using mixed precision.

To use mixed precision, I used these snippets of code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision

policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)

self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
self.optimizer = mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(self.optimizer, loss_scale='dynamic')


for batch_step, batch in enumerate(self.batch_iterator_train):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits, _ = self.model(batch['images'], is_training=True)
            loss_value = self.loss_fn(labels=batch['labels'], logits=logits)
            scaled_loss = self.optimizer.get_scaled_loss(loss_value)

            scaled_grads = tape.gradient(scaled_loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
            gradients = self.optimizer.get_unscaled_gradients(scaled_grads)
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
```

My model is pretty big, and it's using CNN layers if that makes a difference. I thought adding the lossScaleOptimizer would resolve this issue of underflow for the gradients, as described https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision, but it doesn't seem to be working.

While debugging, I noticed that the loss_scale starts from the default max value and then goes all the way down to 1.0; I'm guessing because it detected the nan gradients. But then even at a loss scale of 1.0, I'm still not getting any reduction in loss.

Any ideas or thoughts here would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

My model works fine if I don't use mixed precision by the way.